# Access to Fusion Tables through GAS without a google account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

Is there a way to have a GAS web interface that doesn't require any type of account or login to run queries on a Fusion Table?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to have a Google Apps Script without some kind of account - the author would need one, even if the UI was then published as a public Web App.

I think you *meant* to ask: How can I let non-authenticated users query my fusion table?

**A:** YOU run the script, THEY just see the UI.

Read about [permissions in Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps#permissions). You can publish your web app to Execute as you (the author & authenticated fusion table user), with access granted to Anyone. Then as long as your script manages the table access behind the scenes, the identity of users would be irrelevant.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I guess my problem remains the OAuth 2.0 authorization to the Fusion Tables. Even with your suggested changes, I'm still getting authorization errors: "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials"